# When should I bump dependency version in package.json?

Tags: dependency-management, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

I have a project (called `ingester`), it has a dependency called `sdk`. Currently `sdk` is specified as `^1.30.0` in `package.json`, in `yarn.lock` it's resolved as `1.72.0`. 
I released a new version of `sdk` (1.73.0) and in `ingester` I explicitly use new stuff (classes, functions etc) from `1.73.0`.

Should I bump `sdk` version in `package.json` or it's enough to just run `yarn upgrade sdk` and update `yarn.lock`?
What is the best practice here?

As far as I understand `package.json` should contain the minimum required version of a dependency. In my case it should be bumped to `^1.73.0` because `ingester` will break when using lower version.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, bump the version to the `^1.73.0`. It could be really confusing to read that you need just the `1.30.0` when you really need the `1.73.0` one